# MapPageRoute redirecting wront pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have a ASP.NET MVC3 Razor project. I wanted to add aspx page to this project and I found that it is possible by using MapPageRoute. I added it to my GlobalAsax.RegisterRoutes and it's redirecting me to my aspx page. But also most of the old pages are also redirected to this - they;re getting URL like this:

```
http://localhost:61000/AEM/Report?action=EditUser&controller=Settings
```

My RegisterRoutes method:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "TelerikReport",
            "AEM/Report",
            "~/WebForms/TelerikReport.aspx", true
        );

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
I noticed that it's redirecting pages wrong when I use "return RedirectToAction(...)" in my controllers.

Comment: What do you mean by most of the old pages? Not all, right? One more thing do you have any controller "AEM" and method "Report"?

Comment: Yes, not all of them. I have "AEM" controller and no "Report" method. I've just changed routeURL to "AEM2/Report" and the problem still exists. For example on the start of the application it;s redirecting me to the: http://localhost:61000/AEM2/Report?action=Index&controller=Home when it should be http://localhost:61000/Home/Index

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify your code like:

```
  routes.MapPageRoute(
        "TelerikReport",
        "AEM/Report/{*queryvalues}",
        "~/WebForms/TelerikReport.aspx", true
    );
```

Though I am not sure, but you can give it a try. As explained [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784541.aspx).

Comment: There is still this problem. I noticed that it's happening when I'm using RedirectToAction. I'm using it at the start of application or when user want to access some actions without logging in. Also just after log in, so I simply can't use my app right now.

Comment: If you want to use it before login then pass the last argument as false. i.e. `routes.MapPageRoute(
        "TelerikReport",
        "AEM/Report/{*queryvalues}",
        "~/WebForms/TelerikReport.aspx", false
    );

Comment: Ok, I did it! I just added additional tag, like this: AEM/Report/{Report}/{*queryvalues}. Now i have longer URL, but it's not a problem because I want to display it in Partial View;) Thank you for your help!